# Passing json to thymleaf

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I am using thymeleaf with Spring and want to pass JSON at the view end.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/initiate/{teamplateName}")
ModelAndView
        index(@PathVariable("teamplateName") String templateName) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(templateName);
    System.out.println("Running this");
    System.out.println("Teample name is " + templateName);
    mav.addObject("data", "{ \"dy_t1\": \"This is the text 2\" , \"dy_Lorem\":\"This is the lorem text\"}");
    return mav;
}
```

At the view endm I am trying to extract as `{data.dy.t1}` but it is showing an error. How can I push JSON directly to the template to read values?

Comment: Why would you even do that? Isn't easier to just map it intp some object or if you have a plain JSON, to unmarshall it and send it to the template as an attribute.

Comment: i am getting the data from redis as json , so i want to put this json and pass to the view .

Comment: Wrong approach then! Make an appropriate Java object that represents a JSON from data. Parse JSON from Redis to Java object and set that object as a model attribute.

Comment: yeah , was thinking if i can achieve this directly without any further processing .. anyways thanks will do that way